# Transforming SwiftUI elements in Views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following view that I am creating with SwiftUI:

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {

        VStack {

            Spacer()

            Group {

                Text("Recipes")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.bottom)

                Text("The easiest way to save, search, and share recipes with family and friends.")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.horizontal)

            }

            Spacer()

            Group {

                Divider()

                CustomInput(text: $email, name: "Email")
                    .padding()

                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .modifier(InputModifier())
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing])

                CustomButton(
                    label: "Sign In",
                    action: signIn,
                    loading: loading
                )
                .padding()

            }

            VStack {

                Divider()

                HStack(alignment: .center) {

                    Text("Don't have an account?")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)

                    NavigationLink(destination: SignUp()) {

                        Text("Sign Up.")
                            .font(.footnote)

                    }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {

                        self.error = false

                    })

                }
                .padding()

            }

        }.offset(y: -self.value)
            .animation(.spring())
            .onAppear{

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { (noti) in

                    let value = noti.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
                    let height = value.height

                    self.value = height

                }

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { (noti) in

                    self.value = 0

                }

            }

    }

}
```

What the above is suppose to do it move the textfields up when a user clicks inside any of the two (2) text fields, either email or password.

My question is I would live for the first group which has the application name and short description to totally disappear instead of shift up, since depending on the device size you can still see a clipping of the short description at the top of the device, ex using an iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `@State var keyboardShown = false` property to your view struct. When you set the `value` variable to the height of the keyboard (when keyboard appears) set `self.keyboardShown = true`. And when the keyboard hides set `self.keyboardShown = false`.

Then inside your main `VStack`:

```swift
if !keyboardShown {
    Group {

        Text("Recipes")
            .font(.title)
            .padding(.bottom)

        Text("The easiest way to save, search, and share recipes with family and friends.")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal)

    }
}
```